# Implementing large-area correlated errors in Stim

Tags: stim

I'm looking to implement spatially correlated large-area errors similar to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2466), where a local patch of qubits experience random $I$,$X$, $Y$, $Z$ errors (simultaneously) with some probability $p(r)$, where $r$ is related to the size of the patch.

I can employ the `CORRELATED_ERROR` and `ELSE_CORRELATED_ERROR` instructions to implement this, but because I have to specify each Pauli product, this seemingly becomes intractable as the number of Pauli products grows as $4^N$ for an $N$-qubit error.

Is there some functionality of Stim or a workaround that I'm overlooking that would make this implementable? Or would I have to resort `stim.FlipSimulator` or `stim.TableauSimulator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `stim.FlipSimulator` or `stim.TableauSimulator` for error models with huge numbers of terms. The circuits explicitly list every term, which is intractable when you have a million of them.

It may still be useful to produce a circuit, but with a simplified error model, in order to configure your decoder (unless it also computes terms on-demand).